# create TabBarController in appDelegate?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

This is the first time I use UITabBarController.
Since I have to make all the initial viewControllers that tabBarController will hold, I find appDelegate(where I 'm creating the tabBarController) code is getting longer.
(all the delegate methods of the viewControllers are defined in appDelegate)

Since appDelegate has other things to do such as initializing user data/ handling push notification.. I'd like to move the tabBarController somewhere else.

I guess I could create a dummy controller and create tabBarController over there..
How do people usually create tabBarController application?

Comment: You are exaggerating the overhead. Do it in the appDelegate like everyone else does and save yourself from hours of needless debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I son't know about "usual", but the easy way is to choose the Tabbed Application template in Xcode when you create your project.